# UseStringDeduplication in .NET GC

Tags: .net

Is there something like the the -XX:+UseStringDeduplication JVM parameter for .NET?

Using JetBrains dotMemory I see that there are string duplicates.

[image: dotMemory screenshot]

The amounts wasted is not a lot, but still, it feels like there is room for improvement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short version: no

Longer version:

Wasted is subjective - I'm guessing that most of those are column names from data access or similar; constantly checking every string seen at runtime can get expensive pretty quickly, so while code *can* do this kind of thing, in most cases it would have a strong negative net impact. In almost all cases, these strings will be short-lived and the GC will be very effective at clearing them up, *when* the GC runs (non-deterministic).

The runtime itself can't really do it pre-emptively at the global level when creating strings, because it is a lie that strings are immutable, and it is actually relatively common for *library code* (not application code) to create a string *separately to* filling the string with data as an in-place overwrite. Typical use case here: populating a string from non-contiguous memory buffers without creating an additional linearized copy of the data *before* creating the `string` (i.e. doing 1 copy instead of 2).

If it is your *own* code that is creating the strings (from a file, network, etc), then you could add your own interner code; however, I advise ***not*** using the global interner for this (`string.Intern`) - you'll saturate it and cause negative impact *everywhere*. Instead, use your own scoped interner, perhaps using some kind of dictionary. The problem is that you'll need to write your own comparer for the dictionary that can work on byte ranges as the key.

Comment: My string deduplication works on the ridiculously simple principle of `if s1 = s2 then s1 = s2` at the IO boundary, e.g. when reading records with duplicated string fields from DBs. I don't deduplicate all over, but just at strategic points. That's good enough.